# Editable content in a jquery ui portlet

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, portlet, contenteditable

I'm trying to create jquery ui portlets with editable content (for example a textarea or select boxes).
So far I didn't succeed.

I tried to make the portlet "contenteditable" like this:

```
<div class="portlet">
    <div class="portlet-header">News</div>
    <div class="portlet-content" contenteditable="true">
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit...</div>
</div>
```

The portlet content is then changeable by cut&pasting things into it, but not via keyboard.

I also tried to add a textarea:

```
<div class="portlet">
    <div class="portlet-header">Feeds</div>
    <div class="portlet-content">
        <textarea>bla bla bla</textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

Again the textarea is changeable by cut&pasting things into it, but not via keyboard.

I didn't find any examples that do this. Is this possible at all?

If someone knows a way how to do this without jquery ui I'd be happy to learn about that.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution myself by using [jeditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable):

javascript:

```
    // handle autogrow editable areas in portlets
    $(".autogrow").editable(function(value, settings) { 
         console.log(this);
         console.log(value);
         console.log(settings);
         return(value);
      }, { 
         indicator : "Saving...",
         tooltip   : "Click to edit...",
         type      : 'autogrow',
         submit    : 'OK',
         cancel    : 'cancel',
         autogrow : {
               lineHeight : 16,
               minHeight  : 32
            }
    });
```

html:

```
    <div class="portlet">
      <div class="portlet-header">jeditable autogrow portlet</div>
      <div class="portlet-content" >
        <div>
          <pre class="autogrow" id="paragraph1">
          editable text area inside of portlet
          </pre>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

The only problem I'm still having is that it's not possible to put the text cursor to the right position for editing by clicking it to that position with the mouse. Once you're in edit mode you can only move the text cursor with the keyboard. 
That's different for autogrow areas outside of portlets.
If anyone has a hint how to fix that?

**UPDATE**:
I finally found the simple cause for the last problem (not being able to place the cursor
via mouse clicks inside the jeditable areas in portlets):
just don't use "disableSelection()" as used in the official [portlet demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#portlets).

```
$(function() {
    $( ".column" ).sortable({
        connectWith: ".column"
    });

    $( ".portlet" ).addClass( "ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all" )
        .find( ".portlet-header" )
        .addClass( "ui-widget-header ui-corner-all" )
        .prepend( "<span class='ui-icon ui-icon-minusthick'></span>")
        .end()
        .find( ".portlet-content" );

    $( ".portlet-header .ui-icon" ).click(function() {
        $( this ).toggleClass( "ui-icon-minusthick" ).toggleClass( "ui-icon-plusthick" );
        $( this ).parents( ".portlet:first" ).find( ".portlet-content" ).toggle();
    });

    //COMMENT THIS OUT: $( ".column" ).disableSelection();
});
```